# How to enable microphone in safe mode (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, microphone, audio-recording

my pc works only in safe mode and I need my microphone to work, I managed to fix audio but cannot make the microphone to work. neither my webcam nor my mic works, but the microphone is a priority. Does anyone know the way out?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Super User. Instead of trying to get your microphone to work in safe mode, you should be looking at a way to make your computer work without having to use safe mode. Perhaps you should start a new question or change this question to ask how to fix your computer so you aren't forced to use Safe Mode.

Comment: Safe mode is intended only for fixing things, not for doing regular work. You should focus on fixing the actual problem, not on bypassing safe mode restrictions - it's restricted intentionally to avoid potentially problematic stuff from running.

Comment: I agree as well.

Comment: @SamForbis, thx for the idea but I already have done everything possible to make my PC run in normal mode. my PC isn' stuck in safe mode, it is intentionally started that way as that is the only way. Guys, there must be a way out as I have already overpassed the safe mode restriction of installing apps, sound. I hope i am more clear now

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). Your problem is that your computer doesn't work properly in regular mode. The right question to ask is how to fix this problem. Safe mode works for you _because_ it's restricted. Removing these restrictions somehow would just make it regular mode.

Comment: @XY Problem, as you all r suggesting me to change the question, I feel I must do that. rnx , just hoping someone want refer me to consult manufacturer as i already did